# Using iCloud at work and privacy

Tags: macos, icloud

What is the best way of using iCloud at work, and retaining privacy?

I have work computer, an iMac. Management requires the login password to be known, so that others can use the computer when I am away. That's fair, they bought it. But I want to use my personal iCloud account.

What's the best way of doing this while retaining privacy? Once I have logged in to iCloud, in System Preferences, it seems like anyone could turn on Bookmarks, Photo Stream etc without even asking for my iCloud login.

Answer (score 3):

Is there anything stopping you from creating a separate user account for others to use in the office?

By explaining that the Mac might expose personal information due to the Apple ID on your user account, they should accept that there's a security risk to you if you allow everyone access on that account.

Alternatively, you could try to remember to sign out of iCloud each time you leave, however that wouldn't delete content stored locally already.

Comment: A different account would be too much trouble. I might use your second approach. Perhaps there is even a way of scripting an iCloud logout when logging out of a user: http://www.sns.ias.edu/~cjm/mac-os-x-login-and-logout-scripts-demystified/

Comment: @wildebeesty That's exactly what user accounts are for though. You should create additional accounts for other users to avoid a whole lot of privacy issues, or not use the computer for any privacy sensitive information at all.

Comment: A separate user account would still mean that someone could access files by hooking a firewire cable and restarting in target disk mode..? Unless I use Filevault I guess.. never used that before.

Answer (score 2):

Which features of iCloud do you want to utilize? You may just be able to access them via http://icloud.com in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, iCloud should not be used at a job that is under any regulation.  What is your need to be using iCloud at work?  I'd find another solution to meet your needs.  Maybe a new user is a good idea?  Sharing work documents in a designated folder may be a good solution.